# How to use vee-validate in a parent-child relationship

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a couple of components that need to be validated. The problem is that that inputs are in a child component while the submit button is in the parent like this

ParentComponent.js

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ passes }"> 
     <form @submit.prevent="passes(someSubmitFunction)">
         <ChildComponent />
     </form>
</ValidationObserver>
```

ChildComponent.js

```
     <ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }" name="vendorName">
         <el-input />
      </ValidationProvider>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily there is a pattern for sharing validator scope between parent and child components! You can `inject` the validator from the parent into the child so that they use the same instance. This means that you can validate child inputs from the parent using `this.$validator.validate()`

Docs:
http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/concepts/injections.html

Comment: what's the solution for v3? In v3 , there's no more $validator

Comment: @LiangWang you have to use a ValidationProvider and ValidationObserver. That's about all I know, I chose to stay on v2 since it was much simpler.

Comment: @LiangWang saw this one year later while looking for v4 solution, added a suggested answer below ... so if you're still scratching your head look no further 

Answer (score 5):

For people like me, coming here for guidance in the future with **v4** of **vee-validate** together with **Vue3 Composition API** and **Typescript**, I'd like to suggest this answer. It works by adding each `validate` method from `useForm` to an array and then on form submit it will loop through the array to ensure all validators pass asynchronously.

**formAggregator.ts**

```js
import { InjectionKey, provide, ref } from "vue";

type ValidatorMethodType = () => Promise<{ valid: boolean }>;

export const AddValidatorKey: InjectionKey<
  (validator: ValidatorMethodType) => void
> = Symbol("AddValidatorKey");

export function useValidationAggregator() {
  const validators = ref<ValidatorMethodType[]>([]);

  // used by components to add validators to the array
  const register = (validator: ValidatorMethodType) => {
    validators.value.push(validator);
  };

  // provide this aggregator to components
  provide(AddValidatorKey, register);

  // run all validators
  const validateAll = async () => {
    return Promise.all(validators.value.map((v) => v()));
  };

  return {
    validateAll,
    register,
  };
}
```

**ParentComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <ChildComponent />
   <button type="submit" :disabled="inSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
</template>
<script setup>
import useValidationAggregator from "./formAggregator.ts"
const { validateAll } = useValidationAggregator();
// note: you can use register() to also add validator from the parent component

const inSubmit = ref(false);
const onSubmit = async () => {
   try {
      inSubmit.value = true;

      // run all form validators
      const results = await validateAll();

      // ensure all are valid
      if (results.some((r) => !r.valid)) {
         return;
      }

      // todo: post form or whatever you need after validation passes
   } finally {
      inSubmit.value = false;
   }
}
</script>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
   <!-- some validated fields -->
</template>
<script setup>
import { AddValidatorKey } from "./formAggregator.ts"

const { validate } = useForm({ ... setup validated fields ... });

// add this component's validator to the aggregator
const addValidator = inject(AddValidatorKey, () => {
  throw new Error("No aggregator provided for inject");
});
addValidator(validate);
</script>
```

Comment: firstly Thank You for this solution... small doubt, what if i have multiple models `eg: Project, Task`. How would `validateAll()` only validate the model to which submit button has been clicked?

Comment: @Ankit.Z this solution is only for when a single form has one or many child components

Answer (score 4):

you can overwrite instance of chid component validator by parent component validator in created hook like this.

```
created() {
 this.$validator = this.$parent.$validator
}
```

notice: if you use mounted it dosent work because before DOM rendering replacing must be done.

Answer (score 0):

When running validation for parent ValidationObserver it validate child ValidationObserver too.
If you need validate only parent ValidationObserver you can use "disabled" props for child observer.
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/api/validation-observer.html#props

```js
<ValidationObserver ref="parent">
  <ValidationObserver ref="child" :disabled="true">
    <ValidationProvider rules="required">
      <!-- This child observer will not be validated with parent validation -->
    </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>
</ValidationObserver>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a ref on the child component then try to do a validation on that ref when calling `someSubmitFunction`

Something like this :

```
  const isValid = await this.$refs.childref.validate()
```

Comment: Actually I don't think you can. When I call my child observer ref like this; `const isValid = await this.$refs.consentPanel.validate();` it throws an exception about `validate is not a function`.